# Как вывести категории товара в админке (opencart, детали заказа)?

Tags: php, opencart, вывод, админка

Не могу вывести **категории товара** в "детали заказа" в файле order_info.tpl.
Что и где нужно прописать в контроллере order.php, чтобы получить доступ к категориям товара?

Пробовал так (order.php) комментариями видно что добавил:

```
    foreach ($products as $product) {
                $option_data = array();

                $options = $this->model_sale_order->getOrderOptions($this->request->get['order_id'], $product['order_product_id']);

                foreach ($options as $option) {
                    if ($option['type'] != 'file') {
                        $option_data[] = array(
                            'name'  => $option['name'],
                            'value' => $option['value'],
                            'type'  => $option['type']
                        );
                    } else {
                        $upload_info = $this->model_tool_upload->getUploadByCode($option['value']);

                        if ($upload_info) {
                            $option_data[] = array(
                                'name'  => $option['name'],
                                'value' => $upload_info['name'],
                                'type'  => $option['type'],
                                'href'  => $this->url->link('tool/upload/download', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&code=' . $upload_info['code'], 'SSL')
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }

                $data['products'][] = array(
                    'order_product_id' => $product['order_product_id'],
                    'product_id'       => $product['product_id'],
                    'name'             => $product['name'],
                    'model'            => $product['model'],
                    'option'           => $option_data,
                    'quantity'         => $product['quantity'],
                    'price'            => $this->currency->format($product['price'] + ($this->config->get('config_tax') ? $product['tax'] : 0), $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),
                    'total'            => $this->currency->format($product['total'] + ($this->config->get('config_tax') ? ($product['tax'] * $product['quantity']) : 0), $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),
                        'href'             => $this->url->link('catalog/product/edit', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&product_id=' . $product['product_id'], 'SSL')
                    );


                    //ДОбавил здесь
                   $categories2 = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductCategories($product['product_id']);

                    if ($categories2)
                    $categories_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($categories2[0]['category_id']);
                $this->data['category_title'] = $categories_info['name'];
                //Конец кода

            }
```

Вывод (order_info.tpl):

```
<?php echo $category_title; ?>
```

Выдает белый экран:(

Comment: Не знаю точно, в чем дело, но `name` содержится в таблице `oc_category_description`, при этом может быть несколько значений `name` для разных языков (`language_id`). У вас же в коде языки никак не фигурируют, может дело в этом. А может и нет...

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Упростил код - теперь выдает белый экран